# Convert DSL Query to NEST.net

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have the following `mapping`, I am trying to rewrite it using `NEST` but can't seem to get it quite right yet.

```
PUT company
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {},
        "analyzer": {
          "keyword_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "trim"
            ],
            "char_filter": [],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          },
          "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
          },
          "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 2,
            "max_gram": 5,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "companyId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "companyName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keywordstring": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
            },
            "edgengram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            },
            "completion": {
              "type": "completion",
              "contexts": [
                {
                  "name": "companyGroupId",
                  "type": "category",
                  "path": "companyGroupId"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "companyTradingName": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "companyGroupId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "agencyId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is to where I got, I still need to set the **keywordstring** and **edgengram** to the **CompanyName** field. But not sure how to add the those Analyzers

***MODEL***

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "company")]
    public class CompanyDocument : IDocument
    {
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        public CompletionField CompanyName { get; set; } // <-- I think this needs to be set as an CompletionField 

        public string CompanyTradingName { get; set; }

        public long CompanyGroupId { get; set; }

        public long AgencyId { get; set; }
    }
```

**QUERY**

```
var response1 = this.Client.CreateIndex(
                "testing_testing",
                index => index
                    .Mappings(
                        ms => ms.Map<CompanyDocument>(
                            m => m.Properties(
                                p => p
                                    .Keyword(t => t.Name(n => n.AgencyId))
                                    .Keyword(t => t.Name(n => n.CompanyGroupId))
                                    .Keyword(t => t.Name(n => n.CompanyId))
                                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CompanyName)
                                        .Fields(ff =>
                                            ff.Completion(descriptor => descriptor.Contexts(contextsDescriptor => contextsDescriptor.Category(contextDescriptor => contextDescriptor.Name("CompanyGroupId").Path("CompanyGroupId"))))))
                                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.CompanyTradingName).Index(false)))))
                    .Settings(
                        f => f.Analysis(analysis => analysis
                                .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                                            .Custom("keyword_analyzer", _ => _.Filters("lowercase", "asciifolding", "trim").CharFilters().Tokenizer("keyword"))
                                            .Custom("edge_ngram_analyzer", _ => _.Filters("lowercase").Tokenizer("edge_ngram_tokenizer")).Custom("edge_ngram_search_analyzer", _ => _.Tokenizer("lowercase")))
                                .Tokenizers(
                                    descriptor => descriptor.EdgeNGram("edge_ngram_tokenizer", t => t.MinGram(2).MaxGram(5).TokenChars(TokenChar.Letter))))));
```

**UPDATE**

```
GET company/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "company-suggest": {
      "prefix": "trans",
      "completion": {
        "field": "companyName.completion",
        "fuzzy": {
          "fuzziness": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `companyName` has both `text` and `completion` multi_fields. I'm not sure that works correctly? How do `text` fields know to index data from the `input` array of a completion field?

Comment: @RussCam, this is my first time using completion fields so still trying to figure them out. I changed the companyName Type to completion. I double checked it actually did not make any difference that I had the text type in there. Maybe I am doing it wrong. But I am getting the expected results from my suggestions. Can you maybe explain your last question?

Comment: Sure! `text` and `completion` fields need differently shaped input at indexing time: `text` simply needs a `string`, while `completion` needs an object with an `input` property at least: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#indexing. I'm curious how both are reconciled in the mapping you have. Are you using the `companyName.completion` field in a suggester search?

Comment: Yes i am using companyName.completion, also updated my question so that you can see the query i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to re-write it into NEST, I decided to just use the low-level client.
So i created a `json` file and just reading the contents and then just using the following

```
var response = this.Client.LowLevel.IndicesCreate<CompanyResponse>("index-name", PostData.Bytes(bytes));
return response.ApiCall.Success;
```

This seems a lot easier than trying to recreate the DSL query